# Best way to write test cases for json views? (I.e., web services)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, json, testing

I have a Rails app which implements a web service. I'm not sure how to best write tests for it.

It has one controller. Each method provides json output. As far as I can tell, functional (views) tests would be the right thing to use, but they seem to only work with HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think that you could be good with using a library like [json_spec](https://github.com/collectiveidea/json_spec).

in combination with cucumber this could also server as a documentation for your api-users. have a look at [this nice blog post using json_spec](http://jeffkreeftmeijer.com/2011/the-pain-of-json-api-testing/).